# Alternative to assignment operator overloading

Tags: c#

Let me start off by stating that I know the assignment operator in C# cannot be overloaded/overridden. However, if I have a class like so:

```
public class Time
{

    private int Hour, Minute;
    public int minutes;

    public Time(int m)
    {
        this.minutes = m;
        this.Hour = m / 60;
        this.Minute = m % 60;
    }

    public Time(int hh, int mm)
    {
        this.minutes = 60 * hh + mm;
        this.Hour = hh;
        this.Minute = mm;
    } 

    public static explicit operator Time(int i1)
    {
        return new Time(i1);
    } 

}
```

Two things:

1) Is the explicit conversion overload at the bottom necessary?

2) I want to do

```
Time newTime = 510;
```

and have *Hour* and *Minute* reflect the new *minutes*. Without making another object, is the only way to make a function like so:

```
    public void changeminutes(int m)
    {
        this.minutes = m;
        this.Hour = m / 60;
        this.Minute = m % 60;
    }
```

and do this:

```
Time newTime = new Time();
newTime.changeminutes(510);
```

edit:

I probably should have mentioned that I'm still in learning C#. A lot of your suggestions are flying over my head. Sorry.

next edit :
This isn't necessarily about time. I just used it to illustrate my example.

Comment: Don't you mean `implicit` as opposed to `explicit`?

Comment: I recommend *not* implementing the `Time newTime = 510;` capability.  It is not immediately obvious what is being assigned.  In your final code snippet, I know without having intimate knowledge of the Time implementation exactly what the code is doing.  If the code is not available, `Time newTime = 510;` would be a huge ???? on the part of the readers of the code.

Comment: I recommend following the patterns found in the `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` classes for the purposes of good design.

Comment: What @Inuyasha said. You can see my answer for an example. :)

Comment: You should make your class immutable, and perhaps make it into a `struct`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an implicit cast from `int` to `Time`.

However, I recommend against it.
Unless they're between equivalent types (eg, `int` and `long`), implicit casts will end up creating lots of confusion.
In addition, it isn't obvious that that should mean minutes and not seconds.

You can create a much nicer syntax using extension methods:

```
Time t = 510.Minutes();
```

Comment: Ignoring the confusion element, do I actually need an overload conversion operator at all?

Comment: Do I need to define the conversion (i.e. "public static explicit operator Time" in my example), or would "Time newTime = 510" work without it?

Comment: You cannot have both implicit and explicit casts from the same type.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to make a reference type behave like a value type, which is... um, tricky. If you really don't want to use the constructor for this (and explaining why that is might help us answer), you can use a static "factory" method:

```
public static Time FromMinutes(int m)
{
  return new Time(m);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var t = Time.FromMinutes(510);
```

This is similar to what the [TimeSpan class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromminutes.aspx) lets you do.

Comment: +1 Not sure about the first part, but the second part answers OP's question "is this the only way..."

Comment: TBH, I'm still learning C#. This is more an exercise in learning for me, rather than some I need to know. Just curious how it can be done without making a new object in the process (I come from non-garbage collecting languages). This isn't necessarily about time, I'm just using it illustrate my example.

Comment: @Andrew: No matter what you do, you won't be making an extra object.

Answer (score 0):

For you case an implicit conversion would work but...

Conversions are not to be used when you loose data, or even semantics like in this case. You know that the number will become a Time, but you don't know which unit of time will the number be converted into.

If somebody is going to read the code it will not have any clue what the number represents without looking at the internal definition of the Time class. Think if that was in an outside project. Debugging hell? :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to use `implicit` casting to achieve `Time x = 123;`, but as others are pointing out it's probably a poor design choice because it's not immediately clear what the number represents (and most people would assume a Unix timestamp).

Second, why not use the Minutes property to set minutes, and simply convert the value into the proper value, while changing Hours?

```
time.Minutes = 510;

// in class def:

public int Minutes
{
    get { return minutes; }
    set
    {
        hours = value / 60;
        minutes = value % 60;
    }
}
```